# PHP sesision differences between 5.3 and 5.6

Tags: php, ajax, internet-explorer, session

Recently we upgraded a server from PHP 5.3 to 5.6.  We tested all code internally before doing so, and all was well.

After the upgrade, everything works fine except for an extremely small portion of the clientele.  We have an integration with a LOS called Calyx Pointe.  A small portion of Pointe users are losing their sessions after loading a few pages.  We cannot determine why.

They login and we see their session data.  They choose an option and it redirects them to page #2, which still knows who they are.  They choose an option on that page, which calls an AJAX GET call, and suddenly they're forgotten.  I have verified that the AJAX called page includes the sessions code, so it should be fine.  It's also called via the same domain, so there's no issue w/ multiple domains losing the session.  Also, no _ in the domain name.

When we tested w/ the same version of Pointe, it works perfect for us.  And we have done this on several different versions, using different underlying versions of Internet Explorer.  (Also, a small portion of these users CAN place orders fine.)

So, 2 questions:

Does anyone know of any issue w/ the change in PHP versions that would cause this?  We're not using mysql_* functions.  The sessions are stored in a DB using a modified version of Zebra_Session.  This started immediately after the upgrade (the next day), so I don't feel it's a coincidence.  But, b/c we cannot reproduce the issue, it has made it extremely difficult to diagnose, as we cannot test from the client's machines.

Alternatively, would passing PHPSESSID in the URL to each page called w/in allow each page to "remember" the session?

Any ideas would be helpful and appreciated.

Comment: We had session issues after upgrading from 5.3 to 5.6 as well. I don't know the finer points but ultimately we switched to using Zend Server session clustering to resolve the issue.

Comment: This really isn't an option at this point, but thx for the feedback.